# Can't access my own windows 7 backup image? (Want to only restore dropbox folder)

Tags: backup, windows-8, dropbox

I just got windows 8. Since dropbox takes a bit of time to download 100GB I just wanted to transfer the dropbox folder from the windows backup image. But that doesn't work!! Is it possible that the dropbox folder was not included? Regardless I cannot even access my older user folder when mounting the disk image. Explorer just works and works and never gains access. The backup is there, because I have restored it completely to another HDD. Is there some security feature I've missed? I have tried searching for the dropbox folder using windows own backup tutorial, still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), open it as Administrator, and you'll have access to, at the very least, copy the files.

Moving them will require additional privileges, which means writing to the VHD, which won't work.

That's why it's not working in Explorer, because Explorer needs privileges to access the files under your current user context.

Comment: Perfect. Amazing that windows 8 can't do this.

Comment: It can, but it's more complicated. You'd need to elevate your Explorer to higher privileges, and it doesn't always work. TC always works though, which is why I use it for this sort of thing.